# How to update OpenSSL using Putty and yum command

Tags: ssh, yum, openssl

I am so new to updating server technologies it is unbelievable but we are trying to become PCI Compliant and have to update some of our server technologies. One in particular is OpenSSL.

We are currently running arch i686 0.9.8e but we have to upgrade to ATLEAST 0.9.8g.

When I run a yum update command, there are no updates available. If I run "yum info openssl" it says available packages are: arch i386 0.9.8e but the only difference is smaller file size.

I am running the following repositories:

> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror Loading
>   mirror speeds from cached hostfile  *
>   addons: mirrors.netdna.com  * atomic:
>   www6.atomicorp.com  * base:
>   mirrors.igsobe.com  * extras:
>   mirror.vcu.edu  * updates:
>   mirror.vcu.edu

any help out there?

### EDIT

I am running CentOS release 5.5 (Final)

When I try to manually compile using the following code:

- cd /usr/local/src
- rm -fR openssl-0.9.*
- wget -N
  http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-0.9.8g.tar.gz
- gzip -d -c openssl-0.9.8n.tar.gz |
  gtar xvf -
- cd openssl-0.9.8g
- ./config
- make
- make install
- alias cp=cp
- cp -f /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl
  /usr/bin/openssl
- cd /usr/local/include
- mv openssl openssl.old
- ln -s /usr/local/ssl/include/openssl
  openssl

I get the following error:

> gtar: This does not look like a tar archive
>   gtar: Error exit delays from previous
>   errors

Comment: Why do you need 0.9.8g?

Comment: dont know - that's irrelevant - because the PCI Scanning Organization said so. We need 0.9.8g or more recent

Comment: They probably want you to upgrade due to this brute force vulnerability: http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2008-0166 . If I remember, this was a pretty big deal when it came out.

Comment: Can you provide more details on your CentOS version? Which version of CentOS are you running? What does "lsb_release -a" say?

Comment: @Stefan - I added notes as an edit, running CentOS 5.5 final

Comment: @Stefan: "This patch has never been used by Red Hat, and this issue therefore does not affect any Fedora, Red Hat, or upstream supplied OpenSSL packages."

Comment: And just in case you weren't aware, 0.9.8e-12.el5_4.6 has security patches backported from as recently as **0.9.8n**, so your system will be *less* secure with 0.9.8g.

Comment: @Ignacio - I am just telling you what the PCI compliance company is telling us. Without compliance we cannot process their information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a worst-case scenario, you could always just compile your own version of openssl as an RPM for your system, and then rpm -ihv.

EDIT:  Starting with the source file (.tar.gz), here's what you want to do:

1) Create a new directory to house the RPM hierarchy.

```
# mkdir -p myopenssl/BUILD myopenssl/RPMS myopenssl/SOURCES myopenssl/SPECS myopenssl/SRPMS
```

2) Go into the SOURCES directory, and download your source openssl.tar.gz

```
# cd myopenssl/SOURCES
# mv openssl.tar.gz myopenssl/SOURCES/
```

3) Create a spec file that provides the necessary metadata (you will need to verify all the values are correct)

```
--- spec ----
%define _topdir     /home/user/myopenssl
%define name            openssl
%define release     0
%define version     x.x
%define buildroot %{_topdir}/%{name}-%{version}-root

BuildRoot:  %{buildroot}
Summary:        openssl
License:        GPL
Name:           %{name}
Version:        %{version}
Release:        %{release}
Source:         %{name}-%{version}.tar.gz
Prefix:         /usr
Group:          Development/Tools

%description
Special build of openssl for centos.

%prep
%setup -q

%build
./configure
make

%install
make install prefix=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr

%files
%defattr(-,root,root)
/usr/local/bin/openssl

%doc %attr(0444,root,root) /usr/local/share/man/man1/openssl.1
```

4) After you have a spec file, use the rpmbuild command to build your RPM

```
# rpmbuild -v -bb --clean myopenssl/SPECS/openssl.spec
```

5) Your RPM is built at this point... use the following command to look at the contents:

```
# rpm -Vp RPMS/i386/myopenssl.i386.rpm
```

6) To install it, run the following as root:

```
# rpm -ihv myopenssl.i386.rpm
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how to do that

Comment: The nutshell version is basically you download the source, prepare/compile it into an RPM, and then install the resultant RPM.  For detailed directions, http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-rpm1/.

Comment: this is very helpful, how do you recommend building the spec file? Is there a particular program used to do so?

Comment: Use any text editor... when I first got into linux, joe was the best for me, since it was very much like edit.com from DOS.  nano, vi, vim are also viable, just not as user-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

i tried this solution but i had to fix some lines:

```
* cd /usr/local/src
* wget -N http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.0c.tar.gz
* tar -xzvf openssl-1.0.0c.tar.gz 
* cd openssl-1.0.0c
* ./config
* make
* make install
* alias cp=cp
* cp /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl
* cd /usr/local/ssl/include
* ln -s /usr/local/ssl/include/openssl openssl
```

it worked for me, with centos 5.5